# I am tracing a suspend problem on my Acer Predator Helios 500 Ryzen and I need some help

Tags: suspend, power-management, gnome-power-manager

just a short history: I am unable to suspend with any Linux distribution and be able to resume again.  Currently running Ubuntu 19.04.

I am attempting to follow the steps here to trace the problem: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

This is what I have done so far:

```
$ sudo apt install pm-utils
$ sudo sh -c "sync && echo 1 > /sys/power/pm_trace && pm-suspend"
```

I resumed but got my usual screen garbage (looks like static on the screen). I ssh'd in and did a sudo reboot

Right away I ran this:

```
$ dmesg > dmesg_post_boot.txt
```

I looked for Magic number in the dmesg per the ubuntu wiki above and found these lines:

```
[    0.950964]   Magic number: 0:66:1001
[    0.950965]   hash matches drivers/base/power/main.c:1012
```

Now the instructions are to exclude this module from the next boot and see if I can replicate the problem.  How do I exclude main.c or do I even want to?  Is it even possible that the bug is here?

thanks in advance for any help